# how to implement onRetainNonConfigurationInstance

Tags: android, screen-orientation

i made a media player in android 
it's working great but when i change the screen orientation, the activity is being restarted
i know that this question was already asked on stackoverflow several times 
but none of the answers helped me.
i think i should use: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance

```
    @Override 
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() { ... }
```

but i didn't know the correct way to implement it 
so if someone could give me a tutorial or an implicit example i would be grateful

Answer (score 7):

I believe that `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is deprecated. It will tell you to use `Fragments` instead. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is a link to the `Fragment` documentation. Basically, you will put your UI and data into a custom `Fragment`, then use the `FragmentManager` to store an instance of your `Fragment`. Then, when the activity restarts, you can fetch your `Fragment` and reposition as needed.

Comment: I am currently using a seperate thread for some things, I can imagine that Fragments won't do the trick there.

Comment: And now fragments are deprecated.

Comment: Fragments aren't deprecated. Only native Fragments are. Support Fragments aren't going away any time soon.

Comment: The documentation suggests using Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean) which is deprecated in API level 28.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind that it's deprectated, it works fine. Simplest would be:

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
   return this;
}
```

Then in `YourActivity`'s `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
   YourActivity prevActivity = (YourActivity)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
   if(prevActivity!= null) { 
       // So the orientation did change
       // Restore some field for example
       this.myValue = prevActivity.myValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, it's may be a stupid question, but should i put all the attributes i want to save on the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()  ??????

Comment: Yes, everything you want to save in a form of a single object. So, when you return the whole Activity you get everything back but that's maybe too much perhaps you need only a field or two so you can return your own MyState object. No, no manifest changes are needed.

Comment: But I did in the answer. What's not working? My Activity extends Activity, no fragments.

Comment: yes, my activity extends Activity too, but i'm not getting the result

Comment: Actually the simplest is to declare the variable static, or an element in a static map. Then just expect that it should be there. Eventually they will go away when the activity is finally killed, but it's trivial and kind of persistent (at least in some devices).

Comment: @Tatarize that's wrong, such variable is not saved when the activity is recreated

Comment: @Alex Demonstratively, it is. I've done it for limited purposes and yes, it's preserved over short term use. In fact, it'll remain there until the activity is actually destroyed. At least for a Nexus 7. I'm unaware of any guarantees for how long it will remain. I wouldn't recommend it, but you can try it. I have. It works. And it's well enough to let a bitmap survive a rotate.

Comment: @Alex While obviously it should be considered bad practice. Until the class itself dies, that static will remain in memory. And the class and class loader aren't tossed out of memory until the process is killed, they are kept in memory while the class is loaded. But, even back on the UI stack, it *still* is using that memory. It'll make your program more needing to die, as it's paused state takes actual memory rather than internal memory/disk. But, it will survive until your activity is killed on every implementation I've seen. And rotation doesn't unload the classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my media player, in order not to re-create MediaPlayer completely, I did the following:

1) In AndroidManifest.xml added

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

2) Inside the MainActivity added

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Now, imagine you have multiple orientation-dependant resources, what are your plans, to load them all manually?! Nope, that doesn't slide. You may implement this if you don't have lots of config-dependant resources

Answer (score 0):

[onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance from AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance())
[onRetainNonConfigurationInstance from Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())
If we want to save data

```
data class A(val data: Int)
```

AppCompatActivity

```
override fun onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance(): Any {
    return A(0)
}
```

onCreate

```
val a = lastCustomNonConfigurationInstance as? A
```

If we want to save the object and data.
the object A will live when the screen is flipped.
the object A will be destroyed if the user destroys the screen.

```
class A private constructor() {

    var data: Int = 0
    var isConfiguration: Boolean = false

    companion object {
        private var instance: A? = null

        fun getInstance(
            data: Int,
            isConfiguration: Boolean
        ): A {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = A()
                }
                instance!!.data = data
                instance!!.isConfiguration = isConfiguration
                return instance!!
            }
        }

        fun clear() {
            synchronized(this) {
                instance?.apply {
                    if (!isConfiguration) {
                        instance = null
                    } else isConfiguration = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppCompatActivity

```
override fun onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance(): Any {
    return A.getInstance(0, true)
}
```

onCreate

```
val a = lastCustomNonConfigurationInstance as? A
```

onDestroy

```
A.clear()
```