# why Android Activity retain their state automatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity where I am running a CountDownTimer,if a calls comes or I rotate the screen the timers is still working continuously in some phone but in others phone the timers is not working,and I haven't done anything to retain the state.

So I want to know is there any special feature to these phone to retain the activity state?

here is the code :

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
}.start();
```

Comment: Do  you have a configChanges attribute in the manifest ?

Comment: ya I have a configchanges for admob adActivity

Comment: What's the value ? It needs to be "keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize", the screenSize is for newer version of Android.

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

Comment: Do you have the onConfigurationChanged method in your activity ? (nothing to do, just call the super.onConfigurationChanged)

Comment: No I dont have the onConfigurationChanged method in my activity..

Comment: can u please tell whether it varies between phone to phone or not?

Answer (score 1):

In android is a method that return the last information.

```
> if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
>            CountDownTimer/something       }

@Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return CountDownTimer/something;
    }
```

Comment: What is this I dont understand?I want to know why some phone retain the states...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045846/how-to-implement-onretainnonconfigurationinstance

check this two link...

Comment: so this is for retaining state?but the state is retaining automatically in my phone.

Comment: Yes, Here is retaining state and it retaining automatically.

Comment: but I haven't used these methods still its retaining in my phone.