# Best way to keep object reference in Activity through screen orientation changes

Tags: android, screen-orientation, dagger-2

The only way that I see is to use a `static variable`, but it's not okay as I want to keep the ability to start multiple `Activites`.

In my case, I want to keep a reference of `Dagger 2 Component`.
It will provide objects like `Navigator`. I can't just store it into `Bundle`.

For now, I can't use `Retain MainFragment` instead of `MainActivity` because of this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197271).(I'm at 23 API level)
**Is there any Retain Activity implementation?**

Comment: then store your object in custom `android.app.Application`

Comment: @pskink I already keep Dagger 2's `ApplicationComponent` there :) Now I need a place to hold Dagger 2's `MainActivityComponent`. `ApplicationComponent` dependent on ApplicationContext. `MainActivityComponent` dependent on `SupportFragmentManager()` etc

Comment: Maybe you want to consider using a Loader? They are somewhat more independent of the activities lifecycle and can retain state

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Loaders looks like a solution for processing data, not storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, well you have two built in solutions in android to fix this problem:

1) If the object is serializeable or parcelable you can override onSaveInstanceState() and read the value out in onCreate. Here are the [google developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for the specifics on that.

2) If your object is not serializable you can instead override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and return that object. You can then get the object back in onCreate. Look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17046318) for how to use this approach (don't persist your activity though! persist the object.). The drawback of this is that you can only persist one object at a time.

I have a more in depth write up of these two approaches and third, declarative approach that you can roll. It relies on onRetainNonConfigurationInstance and allows you to use annotations to declare what variables in your activity should be persisted. [check it out here](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/06/declarative-state-management-in-android.html). That said, I wouldn't recommend using this unless you have more than one non-serializeable/parcelable object to persist.

Edit: clarified point that you shouldn't persist your whole activity using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance().

Comment: `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` is that thing that I looking for. Your article is very helpful too. Thanks :)